# Error when I try to upload a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I try to upload a Chrome extension and I get this error:

> An error occurred: Your sentence is not processed.
>
> The package is not found manifesto. Put manifesto manifest.json in the root directory of the zip package.

I have manifest.json in root directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, your ZIP contains the folder with your extension:

```
extension.zip
+-> extension_folder
    +-> manifest.json
    +-> script.js
    +-> resources
        +-> ...
        ...
    ...
```

However, the [docs clearly state](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#create-your-apps-zip-file) that the **root** of the archive should contain the manifest, e.g.

```
extension.zip
+-> manifest.json
+-> script.js
+-> resources
    +-> ...
    ...
...
```

In short: don't zip the folder itself, zip the files in it.

Comment: Check for typos then. And make sure it's not `manifest.json.txt` or similar

Comment: You can try using the Load Unpacked Extension, and load the extension from the root folder. Here is the guide for [Loading the extension to Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)